how to filter equal date with MaskedTextBox in datagridview via BindingList & BindingSource in VB.NET
I'm Trying to to filter equal date with MaskedTextBox in datagridview via BindingList & BindingSource in VB.NET.
but when I create an empty MaskedTextBox then the data is not repopulated or reloaded in the datagridview.
if there is something wrong in my code please guide me
Thanks
Public Class Form1
    Private OrderDetail As List(Of OrderDetail)
    Private _criteriasBindingList As New SortableBindingList(Of OrderDetail)()
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private Sub LoadData()
        OrderDetail = New List(Of OrderDetail) From {
            New OrderDetail() With {
                .Invono = "PI0001",
                .InvoDate = "06-05-2024",
                .ProductName = "TEST 1000",
                .UnitPrice = 15000,
                .Quantity = 20
            },
            New OrderDetail() With {
                .Invono = "PI0002",
                .InvoDate = "07-05-2024",
                .ProductName = "TEST 2000",
                .UnitPrice = 25000,
                .Quantity = 20
            },
            New OrderDetail() With {
                .Invono = "PI0003",
                .InvoDate = "06-05-2024",
                .ProductName = "TEST 3000",
                .UnitPrice = 17000,
                .Quantity = 20
            },
            New OrderDetail() With {
                .Invono = "PI0004",
                .InvoDate = "07-05-2024",
                .ProductName = "TEST 4000",
                .UnitPrice = 18000,
                .Quantity = 20
            }
        }
        _criteriasBindingList = New SortableBindingList(Of OrderDetail)(OrderDetail)
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
    End Sub
    Private Sub myFilter(str1 As String, str2 As String)
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.InvoDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").Equals(str2)).ToList()
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.Invono.ToLower().Contains(str1)).ToList()
        Else
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.Invono.ToLower().Contains(str1) AndAlso c.InvoDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").Equals(str2)).ToList()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.KeyDown
        Dim str1 = txtinvono.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        Dim str2 = MaskedTextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        myFilter(str1, str2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtinvono_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtinvono.KeyDown
        Dim str1 = txtinvono.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        Dim str2 = MaskedTextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        myFilter(str1, str2)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class OrderDetail
    Public Property Invono As String
    Public Property InvoDate As DateTime
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property UnitPrice As Integer
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
End Class

Public Class SortableBindingList(Of T As Class)
Inherits BindingList(Of T)
    Private _isSorted As Boolean
    Private _sortDirection As ListSortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending
    Private _sortProperty As PropertyDescriptor

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SortableBindingList{T}"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SortableBindingList{T}"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="list">An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1" /> of items to be contained in the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1" />.</param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal list As IList(Of T))
        MyBase.New(list)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a value indicating whether the list supports sorting.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SupportsSortingCore As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a value indicating whether the list is sorted.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property IsSortedCore As Boolean
        Get
            Return _isSorted
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the direction the list is sorted.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SortDirectionCore As ListSortDirection
        Get
            Return _sortDirection
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the property descriptor that is used for sorting the list if sorting is implemented in a derived class; otherwise, returns null
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SortPropertyCore As PropertyDescriptor
        Get
            Return _sortProperty
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes any sort applied with ApplySortCore if sorting is implemented
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub RemoveSortCore()
        _sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending
        _sortProperty = Nothing
        _isSorted = False 'thanks Luca
    End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Sorts the items if overridden in a derived class
''' </summary>
''' <param name="prop"></param>
''' <param name="direction"></param>
Protected Overrides Sub ApplySortCore(ByVal prop As PropertyDescriptor, ByVal direction As ListSortDirection)
    _sortProperty = prop
    _sortDirection = direction

    Dim list As List(Of T) = TryCast(Items, List(Of T))
    If list Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    list.Sort(AddressOf Compare)

    _isSorted = True
    'fire an event that the list has been changed.
    OnListChanged(New ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1))
End Sub
Private Function Compare(ByVal lhs As T, ByVal rhs As T) As Integer
        Dim result = OnComparison(lhs, rhs)
        'invert if descending
        If _sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending Then
            result = -result
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function OnComparison(ByVal lhs As T, ByVal rhs As T) As Integer
        Dim lhsValue As Object = If(lhs Is Nothing, Nothing, _sortProperty.GetValue(lhs))
        Dim rhsValue As Object = If(rhs Is Nothing, Nothing, _sortProperty.GetValue(rhs))
        If lhsValue Is Nothing Then
            Return If(rhsValue Is Nothing, 0, -1) 'nulls are equal
        End If
        If rhsValue Is Nothing Then
            Return 1 'first has value, second doesn't
        End If
        If TypeOf lhsValue Is IComparable Then
            Return DirectCast(lhsValue, IComparable).CompareTo(rhsValue)
        End If
        If lhsValue.Equals(rhsValue) Then
            Return 0 'both are the same
        End If
        'not comparable, compare ToString
        Return lhsValue.ToString().CompareTo(rhsValue.ToString())
    End Function
End Class

result from code

